# TestComplete - How can I get the array elements that are stored in their 'var' object when using C#?

Tags: c#, testing, automation, testcomplete

I'm trying to write simple automation test using TestComplete in C#.
(Not JScript/C# Script, just C#)

I'm using their libraries as you can see here:
https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/74747/

and specifically their 'var' type: https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/68791/

I'm trying to identify all the elements on the screen according to specific key and value, using the method "FindAll" (https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/71244/)

```
var a = someProcess["FindAll"]("text", "Simulate", 200, false);
```

In debug mode I can see that "a" has two encapsulated elements that he found and this line passes successfully.

The problem: I'm trying to get the first element, using the line

```
var b = a["0"];
```

and get a 'MissingMethodException'.

If I try to use

```
var b = a(0);
```

it says I'm trying to use variable as a function.

I couldn't find any method that can help me to get the elements.

Comment: should be: `var b = a[0]`

Comment: @jHilscher No it's not working, as "a" is not an array itself, it encapsulates an array.

Comment: This highly depends on what type you are actually getting. Var in C# is basically just a pointer with the addition that .Net is smart enough to dereference it into the actual type itself. The debugger should show you what type you are actually getting and you can lookup from there how to access the encapsulated fields. the [] operator only works if the actual type implements that operator to access its elements.

Comment: @OwlSolo I'm not talking about C# var but on TestComplete's var, as I wrote in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can process such an array in C#:

```
  var font = Connect.Sys["Process"]("notepad")["Window"]("#32770", "Font", 1);
  var a = font["FindAllChildren"]("WndClass", "ComboBox");

  object[] elements = (a.UnWrap() as object[]);
  for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count(); i++) {
    var element = new var(elements[i]);
    MessageBox.Show(element["FullName"].UnWrap() as string);
  }
```